# File Transfer (download) not working on WP8 with phonegap

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8

I am trying to download a file from my server using filetransfer plugin on Phonegap. Everything works fine on Android and iOS. But when building it on WP8 it gets null error.

I think the problem is with the local path do save the file. I have read on windows developers aboud "isostore:/" or "ms-appdata:///" (the second one was something like this) but none of them worked.

I am using phonegap version 3.3.0 and file transfer plugin 0.4.2

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem. In the plugin, if you add a subfolder in the path it does not work. So, When I put just the name of the file in the dl local path it works.

Comment: Could you explain this a little more? Where in the code must you not add a subfolder? You say "in the plugin"; do you mean that you have to modify the plugin to get it to work?

Comment: Yes, I mean when you are giving a path to save file into it, the path should have any folders in it, just the name of the file..

Comment: In other words, one must always download files to the root directory?

Comment: yes that is how it worked for me. Apparently it can not create a folder..
But root in wp8 means root folder of your app not root of SD